# How to create a UID in AssemblyScript for a NEAR contract?

Tags: nearprotocol, assemblyscript

Trying to create a uniqueId in AS.
I added this package
`npm install as-nanoid --save`

The nanoid function from the install is as follows:

```
let urlAlphabet = ['M','o','d','u','l','e','S','y','m','b','h','a','s','O','w','n','P','r','-','0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','N','R','V','f','g','c','t','i','U','v','z','_','K','q','Y','T','J','k','L','x','p','Z','X','I','j','Q','W']

export function nanoid(length: number = 21): string {
  let id = ''
  for (let i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    id += urlAlphabet[i32(Math.floor(Math.random() * 64))]
  }
  return id
}
```

In my assembly `index.ts` file I have the following:

```
import { nanoid } from 'as-nanoid'

@nearBindgen
class MyClass {
  public id: string
  constructor() {
    this.id = nanoid(8)
  }
}
```

Using `NEAR-SDK-AS`
When I initialize the contract after deploying it.
`near call $CONTRACT init --accountId $CONTRACT`

I get the following error:

```
Error: {"index":0,"kind":{"ExecutionError":"Link Error: Error while importing \"env\".\"seed\": unknown import. Expected Function(FunctionType { params: [], results: [F64] })"}}
```

Any help here would be appreciated or if there is a simpler way of creating a uniqueId please share.

Answer (score 2):

```
function generateRandomDna(): string {
  let buf = math.randomBuffer(DNA_DIGITS);
  let b64 = base64.encode(buf);
  return b64;
}
```

Something like this, from the docs, with a variation using available [Math](https://docs.near.org/docs/develop/contracts/as/intro#math) if necessary.

What I do in my contracts, for now, is putting together the account name and block height:

```
const title = context.sender.substring(0, context.sender.lastIndexOf('.'))
this.id = title + '-' + context.blockIndex.toString()
```

Comment: this is great, can you please share where in the docs I can see this?

Comment: I was thinking of just generating the UID in the front-end and pass it as a parameter when creating an instance of the class instead of automatically creating it in AS. Thoughts?

Comment: @andy-dev It shouldn't be a problem, but I would not rely on the front-end too much. That been said, the user can see parameters passed to the function before signing.